# How to select every sixth visible LI element from list available

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is list of filter Items , in UL LI format as shown below. On filter some LI with class "filter-items" will show and hide depends on filter applied.

I want to select every sixth element which is visible after filter and have class **filter-items**, and add ***clear:left*** css

```
<ul>
    <li class="filter-li"></li>
    <li class="filter-li"></li>
    <li class="filter-items"></li>
    <li class="filter-items"></li>
    <li class="filter-items"></li>
    <li class="filter-items"></li>
    <li class="filter-items"></li>
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

I have tried following jQuery selector

```
$(".filter-li:visible:nth-child(5n+1)").css("clear","left");
```

But not getting results I am looking for.

Comment: What is `vehicleFilter` here?

Comment: You must have the `.filter-li` classes in there?

Comment: Sorry .
Updated. 
I meant filter-li instead of vehicleFilter

Comment: This should help you with your nth-selection targeting. It seems `6n` should work for every 6th item. https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "every sixth element which is visible after filter"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` to go through the collection of `li.filter-items`, and select those whose zero-based index matches the sixth element. Every sixth element will leave a remainder of zero when divided by 6, so `index % 6 === 0` will work. However, remember that we are working with a zero-based index, so you will need to check if it leaves a remainder of 1:

```
$('li.filter-items').filter(function() {
  return $(this).index() % 6 === 1;
}).css('clear, 'left');
```

If this is a bit difficult to reason around, you can modify the logic to:

```
($(this).index() + 1) % 6 === 0
```

---

Here is a proof-of-concept example, but I have changed it so that it sets the background color to red for easy identification:

```js
$(function() {
  $('li.filter-items').filter(function() {
    return $(this).index() % 6 === 1;
  }).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="filter-li">li</li>
    <li class="filter-li">li</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 1</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 2</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 3</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 4</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 5</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 6</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 7</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 8</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 9</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 10</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 11</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 12</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 13</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 14</li>
    <li class="filter-items">items 15</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a for loop and develop your own logic like this.
use `$(obj).css("clear","left")` in your case.

```js
var count = 0;
$('.filter-items:visible').each(function(i, obj) {
  count++;
  if(count%6==0){
    $(obj).css("color","blue");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="filter-li ">xx</li>
    <li class="filter-li">xx</li>
    <li class="filter-items">1</li>
    <li class="filter-items">2</li>
    <li class="filter-items">3</li>
    <li class="filter-items">4</li>
    <li class="filter-items">5</li>
    <li class="filter-items">6</li>
    <li class="filter-items">7</li>
    <li class="filter-items">8</li>
    <li class="filter-items">9</li>
    <li class="filter-items">10</li>
    <li class="filter-items">11</li>
    <li class="filter-items">12</li>
    <li class="filter-items">13</li>
    <li class="filter-items">14</li>
    <li class="filter-items">15</li>
    <li class="filter-items">16</li>
    <li class="filter-items">17</li>
    <li class="filter-items">18</li>
    <li class="filter-items">19</li>

</ul>
```